# TypeScript - can Union types be derrived/inferred from a constant list of readonly objects?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I'd like to produce a union type of strings from a constant list of readonly objects that have a string-typed attribute.

example
([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigJQgQwCYHsB2ANiADwDe+mAthAFxQDOwATgJb4DmAvgHwDcAKADGBJlAAeteElQVqdAOTiFXQSPxiQUxCihyatBSBVrRwKAC9tMvZQMKLJgQID0LqAEYAdK-cYhEKwAbhAMUKCQ9MxYeEQgUADaTGycADSMLOwc6clZALq+UACS2FiExFAA7rgAroTYUAAWmCHh4HRQ0TgEFQlKCulGA1AOCgXqYriIAHLyYagJ4l52EKkgy-KpFhs0eVCYYRPAgm7oEAHBoW2RGSkchSVlFdV1Dc2tER39UAA+I8a-EaOASfKBTBCzGgMAAquk+uAAZmCZnMEvgalQ4BBmAVCgAmHxHZEIAAyrDEC3Eay2ewOUCOJz850CITCnyiMR68SSmTStyyOV5HAKp0emHK8Re9SaLWg7M6nLiiX6g2Mg0c4zMxMhoTxunBZKYXiomDAAApwSgeMSdhAAJSMs4XVnXDq5TgPUri561aXvOXtejfP5DQGjEHtbVzaF61DwpHgnUMNEYrE4gRAA))

```js
type Obj = Readonly<{name: string}>;
const x:Obj = {name:'x'};
const y:Obj = {name:'y'};
const z:Obj = {name:'z'};

// 1.
// Receives type: readonly [string, string, string]
// Ideally would have type: readonly ['x', 'y', 'z']
const objNames = [x.name,y.name,z.name] as const;
// Receives type: string
// Ideally would have type: 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
type objNamesT = typeof objNames[number]

// 2. More ideal...  deriving w/ .map over list of objects
const objList = [x,y,z] as const;
// Receives type: readonly [string, string, string]
// Ideally would have type: readonly ['x', 'y', 'z']
const objNames2 = objList.map(obj => obj.name);
// Receives type: string
// Ideally would have type: 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
type objNamesT2 = typeof objNames[number]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You've already thrown away knowledge of `"x"`,`"y"`,and `"z"` before you get you your code below.  If you want that information you need to preserve it at the definition of `x`, `y` and `z`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRBjXw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes it does, thank you! a brief explanation would be awesome if you don't mind. I see how using `satisfies` is significant here, which makes some sense after reading the docs on `satisfies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable with a non-[union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then that's all the compiler will know about the type of that variable. Assigning a value of a narrower type to that variable will *not* [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of the variable to match.  So `const x: Obj = val;` will result in `x` being of type `Obj` no matter what `val` is.

(Note that this is different if the annotated type is a union; then [assignments will narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) the apparent type of the variable to just those union members which match the assigned value.  But `Obj` is not a union, so this doesn't happen.)

And so by the time you get to the parts of your code where you define `objNames`, the compiler has already completely forgotten about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties of `x`, `y`, and `z`.  If you want the ocmpiler to remember, you'll have to declare those variables differently.

---

One reasonable approach is:

- don't annotate the type of the variable at all; let the compiler infer it;
- use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer to infer literal types where possible
- use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check that the value is assignable to the type without *widening* to that type.

For your code that looks like:

```
const x = { name: 'x' } as const satisfies Obj;
const y = { name: 'y' } as const satisfies Obj;
const z = { name: 'z' } as const satisfies Obj;
```

You can see that, for example, the type of `x` is now narrow enough to be useful:

```
// const x: { readonly name: "x"; }
```

And it will still catch if you make a mistake:

```
const w = { name: 123 } as const satisfies Obj; // error!
// --------------------------------------> ~~~
// Types of property 'name' are incompatible
```

---

Now everything works as desired:

```
const objNames = [x.name, y.name, z.name] as const;
type objNamesT = typeof objNames[number];
// type objNamesT = "x" | "y" | "z"

const objList = [x, y, z] as const;
const objNames2 = objList.map(obj => obj.name);
type objNamesT2 = typeof objNames[number];
// type objNamesT2 = "x" | "y" | "z"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigJQgQwCYHsB2ANiADwDeU+mAthAFxQDOwATgJb4DmUAvgHwBuALAAoAMYFmUAB4ooFKrQYByact5RMjKBPxTGmYG0YAzNhG3wEw8ZOBQQchTXpRlIdT03bd+w8bMLWEQbX3sALydKFxVwz28dOyZ-U3NLENFRAHosxL17aQYKFiw8IkdFVwAiaSqBXkzbfKgAdyjKhgBGACYAZg0tPL8jVKCrepyoCBYWXBYAQmzcgFpVtfWNza3t1b4oAD9DpagAFXAg3BMoMFnIFlA3SvVMEqgOCWowfzhCCEawqC4RAAORc2lQAG1pAA6SoAGgcsJcCPCSNoAF0EmEbKBIICQWCTnJcRBLviEKDaIwIfgAK7UODTdE2SYk8mUixE1A1KpQAA+UCqIF5Aqq4Sq-ySQIQABljPZIdIESAUZjBtjRADpRzGN05NK5cxodRMGAABTSlB7aVoiAAShx53ZhL1qBJZO1YJp9MZLHRxzZnqpJ1dgtq-MFwojYqqQA)